# What are most ways to differentiate the same function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

An example of a function that relates to my question: $f(x)=\frac{x^3\left(2x+1\right)^2}{x^2}$ with $x>0$.

That function could be differentiated (at least) 5 different ways *using rules*.

1. Simplify, expand and differentiate each term: $f(x)=4x^3+4x^2+x$ then $f'(x)=12x^2+8x+1$
2. Product rule: $f(x)=x(2x+1)(2x+1)$ then $f'(x)=(1)(2x+1)(2x+1)+(x)(2)(2x+1)+(x)(2x+1)(2)=12x^2+8x+1$
3. Chain rule *with product rule* : $f(x)=x\cdot(2x+1)^2$ then $f'(x)=(1)(2x+1)^2+(x)(2)(2x+1)(2)=12x^2+8x+1$
4. Logarithmic differentiation: $\ln\left(f(x)\right)=\ln\left(x\left(2x+1\right)^2\right)$ then $f'(x)=\left(\frac{1}{x}+2\cdot\frac{1}{2x+1}\cdot2\right)\left[x\left(2x+1\right)^2\right]=12x^2+8x+1$
5. Quotient rule *with product rule*: $f'(x)=\frac{\left(\left(3x^2\right)\left(2x+1\right)^2+\left(x^3\right)\left(2\left(2x+1\right)2\right)\right)x^2-\left(x^3\left(2x+1\right)^2\right)2x}{\left(x^2\right)^2}=12x^2+8x+1$
6. (And then, there is the limit definition of the derivative)

The purpose of the question is to introduce new ways of differentiating with functions that have been used previously. Also, students should think about which way is most efficient, but that only works if there are multiple (rule-based) ways of differentiating the same function.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the pedagogical intention here.

Comment: Some introductory calculus books sometimes introduce a new rule by relating to a previously taught one. For example, with chain rule, they might mention that you could do $(2x+1)^2$ by expanding and differentiating each term, but then if the question was modified to $(2x+1)^{10}$ then it's impractical. The section continues with the student learning about chain rule and then when they get to the exercises, the first few of them sometimes are in the form of "differentiate two different ways". A possible intent is that there are multiple ways to do the same question and check your work.

Comment: You've reached the end of the road of differentiation, then.

Comment: As for your logarithm differentiation question: of course the formula $f'(x) = 8x+4$ is true for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$(as you calculated using the previous rules). However, if you first start out by taking the logarithm, then you have to explicitly assume $x \neq -1/2$, because otherwise $\log\left( (2x+1)^2\right)$ is not even defined. So, even if you obtain the formula $f'(x) = 8x + 4$ using the logarithmic-differentiation method, you will have only established the result for $x \neq -1/2$.

Comment: There is always the "use the definition" route, for terminal masochists... Better look for/classify situations where each of the techinques is the easiest one.

Comment: You can get as many ways as you want by rewriting in various ways --- Rewrite as $1 \cdot (2x+1)^2$ or as $1 \cdot 1 \cdot (2x+1)^2$ or as $1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot (2x+1)^2$ etc. and use the product rule. Rewrite as $(2x+1)^2 + 0$ or as $0 + 0 + (2x+1)^2$ etc. and use the sum rule. Use combinations of these last two ideas, such as $1 \cdot 1 \cdot (2x+1)^2 + 0.$ Be really creative, such as $\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 1} \cdot ((1+1)x + 42 - 41)^{5-3}$ where you also use the product rule when you get to $(1+1)x.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, your last example gave me an idea of how I could incorporate quotient rule into the example question.